# Why its returning an error?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int call()
{
    extern int b;
    b=10;
    printf("%d",b);
}

int main ()
{
    int b=8;
    call();
    return 0;
}
```

Why <strike>is throwing an error like these</strike> do I get the following linker error:

```
 /tmp/ccAsFhWX.o:meka.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `_b' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I wanted to change the b value in the other function using extern keyword but it gives me an error.am i right in doing so ?

Comment: Someone who has already asked 100 question should surely know that they *indent* their code before posting it.

Comment: sorry ! hope i wont do that again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declaring the `extern int b` declares it as.... `extern`. It must be defined elsewhere. If it isn't, drop the `extern` keyword?

I think you wanted a global variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int b;

int call()
{
    b=10;
    printf("%d",b);
}

int main ()
{
    b=8;
    call();
    return 0;
}
```

If you declare the global `b` as `extern` you gain the possibility (and the duty) to define it elsewhere (perhaps in another translation unit (helpers.c) or a library (helpers.a) etc.)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be defined in another translation unit.

Comment: @Vlad ok.... making that _more_ clear (It said '_perhaps_ in another TU' already)

Answer (score 1):

In the C programming language, an external variable is a variable defined outside any function block. Please read about extern variables ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable), for example).

Also, variables have scopes. For example, it can be a local variable, a global variable etc. You can read more about that [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29).

So what you have done here is declared a function scope variable in function `call ()` without defining it using the power of extern keyword. In other words, simply tells the compiler that variable already exists somewhere. On top of that, you declared and defined another function scope variable in function `main ()`, which has the same name. It is important to understand that those variables are totally different. So at the end of day, when you link your program, the definition of the variable `b` for function `call ()` is not found. You declared it but never defined, remember?

Here are possible solutions. Do not declare multiple `b` variables as that was clearly not your intent. Stick with a single declaration and definition:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

extern int b;

void call()
{
    b = 10;
    printf("%d\n",b);
}

int b = 8;

int main () {  
    call();
    return 0;     
}
```

But global variables are usually very bad - global scope makes them extremely [pipeline unfriendly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol), introduce threading issues etc. So you must look into something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

void call (int *b)
{
    printf ("%d\n", *b = 10);
}

int main () {  
    int b = 8;
    call (&b);
    return 0;     
}
```

I'd also recommend you read [the following question and answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c). It explains a lot about extern variables in C.

And by the way, you function `call ()` is declared with `int` return type but returns nothing.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To change the "b" in main(), you must pass a pointer to "call" like `call (&b)` and then do

```
void call (int *b) {
    *b = 10;
    printf("%d",*b);
}
```